# Loop with children in c#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I am trying to modify children of parents in c#.
As you know it's impossible to do that in a foreach, to explain my issue in a better way, here is what I've coded at first :

```
foreach (GantLineItem proj in Tasks)
{
    foreach (GantLineItem jalOrMach in proj.Children)
    {
        if (jalOrMach.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GantLineItem machOrServ in jalOrMach.Children)
            {
                if (machOrServ.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    GanttView.ExpandCollapseService.CollapseItem(machOrServ);
                }
                //else     jalOrMach.Children.Remove(machOrServ);
            }
            GanttView.ExpandCollapseService.CollapseItem(jalOrMach);
        }
        //else proj.Children.Remove(jalOrMach);
    }
    GanttView.ExpandCollapseService.CollapseItem(proj);
}
```

So, each time, my else can't be executed.

To fix this issue I've try to do that with a for loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < Tasks.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < Tasks[i].Children.Count; j++)
    {
        for (var k = 0; k < Tasks[i].Children[j].Children.Count; k++)
        {

        }
    }
    GanttView.ExpandCollapseService.CollapseItem(Tasks[i]);
}
```

But here, I am having a new problem, the line

```
for (var k = 0; k < Tasks[i].Children[j].Children.Count; k++)
```

can't be executed, the "Count" is not possible to do in this case, why?

Comment: "the "Count" is not possible to do in this case," > Why not? Compilation errors? Other things? Please be specific.

Comment: What type is `Children`?  It's it's `IEnumerable<T>` there would be no `Count` property, for example.  You could use the LINQ *method* `Count()`, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's true that I was not enough precise : Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

Comment: @CharlesMager I tried it : Count(Tasks[i].Children[j].Children), it doesn't work either... The type is IEnumerable...

Comment: just a tip : always start from Count and traverse back .. so K = count-1; k >=0; k-- ..... this way if you remove items, it wont affect the iteration

Comment: @Muds - To be fair if you count backwards you are not "iterating" as such - you are merely indexing in a way where you know that removing elements won't affect the next lower index - and this only works for indexable collections.

Comment: that's right but if you try and remove from a collection while iterating you will be in trouble, indexing backwards is the easiest and least expensive imo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the final `Children` property is `IEnumerable<T>`, so the `Count` that is resolved is the LINQ *extension method* `Enumerable.Count`.  There is no `Count` property.

Change:

```
for (var k = 0; k < Tasks[i].Children[j].Children.Count; k++)
```

To:

```
for (var k = 0; k < Tasks[i].Children[j].Children.Count(); k++)
```

However, in order for the indexes to always remain valid you would need to do this in reverse.  The simplest solution is usually to clone the collection you're iterating.  This would not cause an error, for example:

```
foreach (GantLineItem proj in Tasks.ToList())
{
    Tasks.Remove(proj);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work, I really don't understand, I translate my error and I give it to you :)

Comment: Thank your for helping dear ! My error : system.collections.ienumerable' does not contain a definition for 'count'

Comment: You likely need to make sure there is a `using System.Linq;` in the using declarations.

Comment: Yes, yes, I did that, but still... :(

Comment: so whats your current error ? I think Charles's ans should suffice, please tell where are you stuck now ?

Comment: it says that Tasks[i].Children[j].Children.Count is not an int

Comment: Ah, your collection simply iEnumerable not IEnumerable<T>.  Replace Count() with Cast<object>().Count() (replace object with correct type).

Comment: that should be it now :)

Comment: I thank you a lot, it is my two firsts weeks in my company and I have to work a somebody's program... After only 2 years of IT studies where I have not learn C# it's quiet hard... ^^ So thank you for your helpful answer !